# Ctrl + Page UP / Page Down are reversed

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I use Ubuntu, KDE and xfce. All the shortcuts for changing tabs or anything involving the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> instead of going right, it goes left (down) .

1. How can I change that?
2. Is that the correct way?

Am I the reverse here ? :)

Comment: English is read from left to right, so it makes sense that Page Down (i.e. move forward in a document) would move to the right. At least that's how I think about it.

Comment: Still if you think about it's a mind blowing :P

Comment: I dont'see how moving tab is related to how we write. When you move the sound volume up you prees the up arrow. On your amplification you turn your button right to make volume goes up.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to rebind the effect of <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> keys (and any other key for that matter).

In Ubuntu 20, you can use `xmodmap` for that effect.

First, generate the current keycode map:

```
xmodmap -pke > .Xmodmap
```

Then you can use `xev` to find the code of any key.

```
xev -event keyboard
```

On my computer, <kbd>Page Up</kbd> is 112 and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> is 117. The output of `xev` for one key press looks something like this

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6000001,
    root 0x756, subw 0x0, time 12213220, (1372,343), root:(2562,445),
    state 0x10, keycode 112 (keysym 0xff55, Prior), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6000001,
    root 0x756, subw 0x0, time 12213311, (1372,343), root:(2562,445),
    state 0x10, keycode 112 (keysym 0xff55, Prior), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Keep *only* the lines related to the two codes you found in the file `.Xmodmap` file, and invert their content. Save the file, and  commit it as the current keycode map with `xmodmap .Xmodmap`.

Voilà! The keys works like your intuition tells you (I also think in a reverse way, since I mostly use those keys to switch tabs on a layout with pageup above pagedown ;) )

To make it work on every reboot, we need to set a command as a "startup application". Open `Startup Application` program, put the command resulting from the following as the task

```
echo -e "xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap"
```

Then save the task, make sure your `.Xmodmap` file is actually at `$HOME/.Xmodmap`, **reboot** your system, and the remap should work on boot. It might not work on system hibernation though.

This methodology was adapted from the [Remap keys in the keyboard in Ubuntu](https://dev.to/0xbf/remap-keys-in-the-keyboard-in-ubuntu-5a36) article on [dev.to](https://dev.to). The answers to the following question on UbuntuAsk also talk about `Xmodmap`, for a different perspective: [Ctrl + Page Down && Ctrl + Page Up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105224/ctrl-page-down-ctrl-page-up). I could not make it work using xkbcomp, but I didn't try super hard either.